# SСSS nesting: how add class to a previous parent element

Tags: css, sass

Let's take a look at this example:

```
.box {
    padding: 1rem;
    .item {
        paddding: 1rem;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        a {
           color: #000;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to add here new rules with pseudo-class.
**How to make it with SCSS to get this output?**

```
.box .item:first-child a:first-child {display: none;}
.box .item:last-child a:last-child {display: none;}
```

I know that I can use `&` parent selector and it works with `<a/>` to set the pseudo-class:

```
a {
    color: #000;
    &:first-child {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

But what should I do to set the pseudo-class to the **previous** parent `.item`?

---

**UPDATE**

Any way to do it with no dublicate the selectors? Smth like this:
`a { color: #000; $parent(has:first-child) {display: none;} }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create specific nested rules for it:

```
.box {
    padding: 1rem;
    .item {
        paddding: 1rem;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        a {
            color: #000;
        }
        &:first-child,
        &:last-child {
            a {
                &:first-child,
                &:last-child {
                    display: none;
                }
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

There is no refactored way to this I believe.

Comment: Without nesting: `&:first-child a:first-child, &:last-child a:last-child { display: none; }`

Comment: It does work. But is there any much overnice way to do it with NO dublicate `a` selector? Imagine smth like this, maybe: `a { color: #000; $prevparent(has:first-child) {display: none;} }` - to write less :)

Comment: @eleave I don't think it's possible with sass. You can store the `a` in a variable if you don't want to write it twice.

Comment: Yeah like @Arkellys said, it is currently not possible.

Comment: I got it, thanks for idea with store selectors in variables, i did not think about it.